# Netbeans not running PHPUnit tests

Tags: netbeans, phpunit, php-7

I am running PHP7.1 in the latest Netbeans version and am trying to run PHPUnit 6.5 along with it.  When I run the tests in Netbeans, they are not executed and the output window gives the following stacktrace:

```
"C:\bin\phpunit.bat" "--colors" "--log-junit" "C:\Users\rwinkler\AppData\Local\Temp\nb-phpunit-log.xml" "C:\bin\phpunit.phar"

Fatal error: Uncaught PHPUnit\Runner\Exception: Class 'C:\bin\phpunit' could not be found in 'C:\bin\phpunit.phar'. in phar://C:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Runner/StandardTestSuiteLoader.php:102
Stack trace:
#0 phar://C:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php(130): PHPUnit\Runner\StandardTestSuiteLoader->load('C:\\bin\\phpunit', 'C:\\bin\\phpunit....')
#1 phar://C:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php(73): PHPUnit\Runner\BaseTestRunner->loadSuiteClass('C:\\bin\\phpunit', 'C:\\bin\\phpunit....')
#2 phar://C:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php(169): PHPUnit\Runner\BaseTestRunner->getTest('C:\\bin\\phpunit', 'C:\\bin\\phpunit....', Array)
#3 phar://C:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php(148): PHPUnit\TextUI\Command->run(Array, true)
#4 C:\bin\phpunit.phar(570): PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main()
#5 {main}
  thrown in phar://C:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Runner/StandardTestSuiteLoader.php on line 102
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PHPUnit\Runner\Exception: Class 'C:\bin\phpunit' could not be found in 'C:\bin\phpunit.phar'. in phar://C:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Runner/StandardTestSuiteLoader.php:102
Stack trace:
#0 phar://C:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php(130): PHPUnit\Runner\StandardTestSuiteLoader->load('C:\\bin\\phpunit', 'C:\\bin\\phpunit....')
#1 phar://C:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php(73): PHPUnit\Runner\BaseTestRunner->loadSuiteClass('C:\\bin\\phpunit', 'C:\\bin\\phpunit....')
#2 phar://C:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php(169): PHPUnit\Runner\BaseTestRunner->getTest('C:\\bin\\phpunit', 'C:\\bin\\phpunit....', Array)
#3 phar://C:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php(148): PHPUnit\TextUI\Command->run(Array, true)
#4 C:\bin\phpunit.phar(570): PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main()
#5 {main}
  thrown in phar://C:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit/Runner/StandardTestSuiteLoader.php on line 102
Done.
```

My test is a sample test I pulled from a tutorial:

```
<?php
require_once 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php';
declare(strict_types=1);

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

final class EmailTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testCanBeCreatedFromValidEmailAddress(): void
    {
        $this->assertInstanceOf(
            Email::class,
            Email::fromString('user@example.com')
        );
    }

    public function testCannotBeCreatedFromInvalidEmailAddress(): void
    {
        $this->expectException(InvalidArgumentException::class);

        Email::fromString('invalid');
    }

    public function testCanBeUsedAsString(): void
    {
        $this->assertEquals(
            'user@example.com',
            Email::fromString('user@example.com')
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: i guess you have misconfigured Project properties -> Testing -> PHPUnit -> Use custom test suite (leave it empty)

Comment: Thank you, xmike.  This was the problem exactly.

Additionally, for anyone else that comes across this later, the next problem I found after removing the custom test suite from the settings was that I did not use an include in the test file for the class I was testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per xmike in the comments:

"i guess you have misconfigured Project properties -> Testing -> PHPUnit -> Use custom test suite (leave it empty) "